# LDAP Query - Include/Exclude Groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Trying to amend a rule to exclude certain group from my existing functioning query...
When i add the extra section to exclude, groupC, it picks up no users.

```
(&
    (objectclass=user)
    (&
        (|
            (memberOf=groupA)
            (memberOf=groupB)
        )
        (!
            (memberOf=CN=GroupC)
        )
    )
)
```

Have tried tweaking syntax, adding extra parenthesis, and extra &, with no change.

Comment: What is your server? Active Directory, OpenLDAP, etc.?

Comment: Apologies... Active Directory.

Comment: The call coming from 3rd party app pulling users into repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory requires the full distinguished name in queries when you're matching an attribute that takes a DN, like `memberOf`. So just `CN=Group3` isn't enough, and getting no results is exactly what would happen. Besides that, your syntax is correct.

It should look more like this:

```
(&
    (objectclass=user)
    (&
        (|
            (memberOf=CN=groupA,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com)
            (memberOf=CN=groupB,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com)
        )
        (!
            (memberOf=CN=GroupC,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...
The full DN is being used.... for the example i probably reduced it too far.

The existing is

(&
 (objectclass=user)
  (|
    (memberOf=CN=groupA,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com)
               (memberOf=CN=groupB,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com) 
  )
)

Comment: So the suggested answer is akin to what i'm using...
Any reason why this wouldn't work? 

Looking for where user in group A OR B but not C?

Comment: @user21258641 I couldn't tell you. I just tried it myself and it worked.

Comment: Sorry... Cheers... Removed the formatting and processing as expected.
Thanks for your help @Gabriel Luci